# Suggest a weekend learning track for MVC3 for someone familiar ASP.NET web forms development

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a "green field" project I'll be starting monday, and it's an intranet business application that wants to do all the typical stuff like workflow, alerts. The Model is done with EF and has all the core entities that a 50 person company would be expected to have plus a model of business specific accounting procedures - every entity corresponds to a noun in the employees' nomenclature.

I spent a good deal of spare time in the past few months learning sharepoint 2010 and it definately has facilities for everything this project wants to be (think enthusiastic business owner who recently woke up to the possibilities of life beyond excel sheets).  I may not have the opportunity to get up on the sharepoint curve quickly enough and this means writing it from scratch.

The main things I need to deal with are:
- grid style data forms
- active directory based authentication
- email integrated alerts and event driven workflow
- professional appearance similar to default sharepoint 2010 theme

I know how I'd do it with web forms.  It would not be trivial by any means - Providers, .ASCX Controls, Validators, Masterpages, Themes, Skins, tied together with a project specific class library to support cross-cutting issues.  I have this architecture in my mind and it's worked for me on other projects - I can predict to myself the success and schedule, which makes my stress level manageable.

That said, I get the distinct imppression from the "blog-o-sphere" that I'd be doing myself a disservice if I didn't at least try to use MVC for this.

I started researching and found the [Documentation Resources for ASP.NET MVC 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416514%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) and, well, I just don't know where to begin.

I have this weekend to decide if I can do it because Monday I've gotta go in with a game plan.

If, from my description, someone could recommend a tutorial and/or a clean open source example, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Good question, I am interested in seeing some results as well.

Comment: "a tutorial and/or a clean open source example": http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/ - I haven't gone through it, but it contains the bits you're interested in, and is written by several MSTies for demoing MVC 3, Razor, and EF.

Comment: Well, unless you do not have a deadline do not try something NEW in a real life project.... Better to stick to what you know best and learn MVC in your spare time.

Comment: @Pleun, it's fine advice that i follow often - the first version of this is the WinForms app I made over the course of the last 14 months - it served to extract requriemnts and I provided fast feature churn - the result is a stable model, but the world is moving on and I want by employers software solutions to move with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you get [this book](http://www.apress.com/9781430234043) (e-book version). It contains a real walk through example on the first chapter that you can follow, and then as you move along, the author also tells you why you do certain things the way the are. I'm sure with your experience (as you describe) with webforms, this book should be sufficient for you to make a decision over the weekend.

Just out of curiosity though (in a pragmatic point of view), if you believe you can do this easily using webforms, why the trouble learning MVC over the weekend? Wouldn't you be disservicing yourself then :)?

Comment: thank you - well i'm turning 36 this month and all the kids these days are going to seeing me as a fuddy duddy - the way i'd regard someone who, say, today tried to appraoch this problem with classic ASP

Comment: @Gabriel - yes - the great advantage of ASP.NET MVC over Web forms if you have the model already is that the UI can be built as "scaffolding" on top. Getting something ugly-but-working can be done with a few method calls, and Visual Studio will create much of that for you. Then, as you extend the application and make it usable and attractive, the steps are fairly straightforward: you won't need to throw away what you've done, but can build on it. So stick with it, it's worth the effort!

Comment: @Gabriel If you read the book, follow the example and also read other sources then you should be fine and have a good feeling about ASP.NET MVC (3). It's also the most recommended book.

Answer (score 4):

For me, a real world sample is always the most useful where to start :

http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

There is a real world sample there called **The Contoso University Web Application**

The following conference session videos are great the start with also :

**MVC 3 – 101 by Scott Hanselman** : 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/DevDays/DevDays-2011-Netherlands/Devdays002

**ASP.NET MVC 3 @:The Time is Now by Phil Haack** : 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM03

**ASP.NET + Packaging + Open Source = Crazy Delicious by Scott Hanselman** : http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/PDC/PDC10/FT01

And there are so many out there on [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.asp.net/mvc has pretty much what you need.